# Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner : how to configure Wiremock server?

Tags: wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

```
package com.example.stubrunner;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.server.EnableStubRunnerServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfigurationCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
public class StubRunnerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StubRunnerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public WireMockConfigurationCustomizer optionsCustomizer() {

        WireMockConfigurationCustomizer customizer = new WireMockConfigurationCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration config) {
                config.jettyHeaderBufferSize(16384);
            }
        };

        return customizer;
    }

}
```

Above customizer bean does not seem to have any effect. This feature has not much documentation. With security token headers Wiremock's (jettty) default value is just too little.

I used start.spring.io with (current) defaults: spring boot 2.5.5. and spring cloud Hoxton.SR3.

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.26.3.jar --jetty-header-buffer-size 16384
```

works just fine.

EDIT :

```
package com.example.wiremockrunnerlatest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.server.EnableStubRunnerServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(httpServerStubConfigurer = HeaderSizeConfigurer.class)
public class WiremockRunnerLatestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WiremockRunnerLatestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

... and then :

```
public class HeaderSizeConfigurer extends WireMockHttpServerStubConfigurer {

    @Override
    public WireMockConfiguration configure(WireMockConfiguration httpStubConfiguration, HttpServerStubConfiguration httpServerStubConfiguration) {

        return httpStubConfiguration.jettyHeaderBufferSize(16384);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer for us for now is, use plain Wiremock standalone, and forget about SCC stub runner. 
The idea of “stub runner” is nice, but incomplete in terms of options to configure it.

Comment: You're using the wrong customizer. Please check https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-configuring-http-server-stubs where we describe how to use stub runner with wiremock configuration. " comes with an implementation that you can extend for WireMock: org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.provider.wiremock.WireMockHttpServerStubConfigurer. In the configure method, you can provide your own custom configuration for the given stub. The use case might be starting WireMock for the given artifact ID, on an HTTPS port. "

Comment: Added after EDIT:  does not help. Is there any working example, test or something that I could check?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfigurationSpec.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @AutoConfigureStubRunner annotation?

Just add below annotation in your tests:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
    ids = "com.org:servicename:+:stubs")
```

Here stubsmode is classpath which means that stubs would be available in classpath.

to do that add:

```
testCompile("com.org:servicename:+:stubs") { transitive = false }
```

in your build if your using gradle or add equivalient from maven.
This will download the application automatically from remote and configures the wiremock server for stubs to be available.

complete configuration to run a spring boot test is like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
    classes = HiltiIntegrationApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
    ids = "com.ict:organization-management:+:stubs")
@DirtiesContext
```

Hope this helps!